# Add extra space on list items

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

I encountered a really simple problem that cost me one question in competition just because of whitespace.

The code goes like this:

```
import numpy as np
import math

rows, columns = map(int, input().split()) 
mat = np.array([list(map(int, input().split())) for row in range(rows)])

print (np.mean(mat, axis = 1))
print (np.var(mat, axis = 0))
print (np.around(np.std(mat), decimals=11))
```

So if the inputs are:

```
2 2
1 2
3 4
```

The output would be:

```
[1.5 3.5]
[1. 1.]
1.11803398875
```

While the expected output is:

```
[ 1.5  3.5]
[ 1.  1.]
1.11803398875
```

And generates "Wrong Answer". How to add extra space on list so it could get accepted?

Comment: It looks like they're expecting different [`printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html), maybe they have `sign=' '`.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks @jonrsharpe